# What are the metrics sent to Prometheus + Grafana in a generated jhipster project?

Tags: logging, prometheus, jhipster, grafana, metrics

I running a gateway and a microservice using jhipster docker compose and i have chosen to generate metrics with prometheus but i couldn't visualize what's in the grafana because the gateway failed to run?

Can anyone tell me what application metrics are normally provided to prometheus+grafana? And does logs are also provided to prometheus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metrics are sent to Prometheus if this property is set to true:

```yaml
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
```

For more details check documentation for [Spring Boot Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics) and [Spring Metrics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-metrics/docs/current/public/prometheus). You'll find the name of all metrics exported to Prometheus/Grafana.

Logs and metrics are 2 different things, logs are not sent to Prometheus, logs are either written to file system or sent to Elasticsearch through Logstash.

As of version 7, JHipster does not provide any ELK stack docker deployment and ready to use dashboards but the log export using logback logstash appender is still configured. So, you can either configure your own docker-compose ELK starting from an [existing one](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) or use one from a cloud provider (Elastic Cloud, AWS, Datadog, ....). It's not that difficult now that you have to deal only with logs, in the past JHipster used also ELK for metrics and this was a large part of the ELK dashboards they provided.

Comment: okay, i will read the documentation many thanks

Comment: I also get an error related to the gateway not running even though it's up in the docker compose

Comment: Please open a new question with much more details about this issue.

Comment: I did here is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73486651/gateway-not-appearing-in-the-jhipster-registry

Comment: Please what about the ELK stack, i read that it is not maintained anymore nor supported by jhipster 7, is there an alternative to process logs in a jhipster project?

Comment: I just realized you added the answer!! thank you so much, your answer is so helpful :)