# Gateway not appearing in the jhipster registry

Tags: jhipster-registry, jhipster-gateway

I have created a docker image for the gateway application, but when i run the command:
docker-compose up
only the microservice and the registry are UP but the gateway is not even appeared in the intances

22-08-25 10:57:23.661 ERROR 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
mygateway_1                |
mygateway_1                | org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration' defined in file [/app/classes/ma/s2m/nxp/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in file [/app/classes/ma/s2m/nxp/security/DomainUserDetailsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in ma.s2m.nxp.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on DatabaseConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#139c4f36' of type [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragmentsFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'repositoryFragments'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#139c4f36': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepositoryInternalImplFragment': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userRepositoryInternalImpl' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepositoryInternalImpl' defined in file [/app/classes/ma/s2m/nxp/repository/UserRepositoryInternalImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'r2dbcDatabaseClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/r2dbc/ConnectionFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'r2dbcDatabaseClient' parameter 0; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/r2dbc/ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration$PooledConnectionFactoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.r2dbc.pool.ConnectionPool]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create a ConnectionFactory for 'ConnectionFactoryOptions{options={driver=postgresql, database=myGateway, host=mygateway-postgresql, port=5432, user=myGateway}}'. Available drivers: [ h2, pool ]

Comment: Well the error seems to say that your app cannot connect to your postgresql db: "Unable to create a ConnectionFactory for 'ConnectionFactoryOptions{options={driver=postgresql, database=myGateway, host=mygateway-postgresql, port=5432, user=myGateway}}'. Available drivers: [ h2, pool ]"

Comment: so what should i do to overpass the error, normally everything is configured bu default by jhipster and docker compose isn't it?

Comment: What is your developer level?

Comment: I am a junior developer

Comment: OK, so why do you want to use a microservices architecture? What are the benefits you expect versus the added complexity? I predict you will have hard time to master it, your productivity will drop and potentially you will fail unless you have a senior developer mentoring you. For example, you will have to learn Spring Cloud in addition to Spring Boot, how many weeks do you have for this extra learning?

Comment: I am learning almost everyday new concepts and trying to understand more and more jhipster and its architecture. I don't know honestly, I am working on this project since 2 weeks and I am pursuing to do so! according to your experience how much would that need? and I'll learn more about Spring Cloud and Spring boot to master that more! what other blocs i need to know besides?

Comment: The list of all technologies used in JHipster is available in https://www.jhipster.tech/, I would say that there are 10 of them on backend and 8 on frontend. While you are learning technologies that will change over time, you may not spend enough time learning on the most important skill that will help you for your whole career: business modeling, learn about Domain Driven Design, hexagonal architecture. If you are thinking of adding a list of techs on your CV, keep in mind that unless your project has been in production under heavy load, this knowledge is not as valuable as you may think.

Comment: To master Spring Boot and Hibernate, I would say it takes few years. To get comfortable with them: 3 months. You will learn things more in depth if you start with a monolith

Comment: alright thanks, i would take all you said into consideration